# Partial screen refresh glitches and delayed updates on integrated display, not when using external

Tags: gui, graphics

I'm on a brand new Lenovo Yoga slim 7 14IIL05 (nvidia MX350 and integrated Intel graphics). It was a pain to get anything running here properly in the first place, I tested many distros and kernels, finally I landed on archlinux (latest 5.9.6 kernel, running KDE 5.2) where the touchpad works reliably.

The issue I'm having persisted in pretty much every distro I tested previously (Ubuntu, Mint, Debian, Fedora, different DMs). It's quite hard to describe and even harder to search for on the internet. When writing small text in the console or this question, every second character renders, sometimes when I switch tabs in Firefox/Chrome the tab switcher updates but the window stays where it was and will update in lines as I drag the mouse through or at once if I resize the window, the mouse pointer gets often doubled after leaving it stationary for a while and disappears afterwards, etc... Generally whenever something forces large screen repaint glitches disappear.

Interestingly it doesn't matter what I set in System Settings as Compositor parameters, there is no difference between "Full screen repaints" and "Reuse screen content" (settings which made huge difference on my old laptop). It isn't web browser dependent happens everywhere.

I'm running the nvidia driver and the i915 driver, both seem to work just fine, still not sure how to check which GPU is being used but I guess I'm on the Intel one. Tested nVidia using optirun glxspheres64.

Answer (score 2):

After further research, I figured that this problem was caused by Lenovo Yoga Slim 7's **Panel Self Refresh** feature, which is enabled by default. Disabling it fixed everything for me.

Step 1: edit GRUB

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Step 2: disable the PSR (Panel Self Refresh), by editing the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_psr=0"
```

Step 3: Update the GRUB

```
sudo update-grub
```

There it is to it. I found this from an Arch forum, but I don't remember which forum. Here's another post regarding this issue https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2021/09/01/linux-thinkpad-screen-flicker/

Comment: If you got the answer from somewhere, you should  *link*  to the source.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had an issue with the upper 1/4 of my screen and was looking for a solution for months. I tried more than 10 other distros with the same or even much worse issues. I always thought about nvidia having issues but not about the intel card.

Comment: For me the problem was the other way around: integrated display was fine but external screen connected via HDMI was having glitches. This solution fixed it, thanks!